# Form action status message after successful submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

A form deletes all the data on a page (example.php) stored in MySql database that is relevant to the sql command.

The code details are as following:

```
if ((isset($_POST['id'])) && ($_POST['id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));


  mysql_select_db($database_example, $example);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $example) or die(mysql_error());


  $deleteGoTo = "example.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}

$colname_deleterecord = "5";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $colname_deleterecord = $_GET['id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_example, $example);
$query_deleterecord = sprintf("SELECT id, user_name, email, address FROM users WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_deletetrecord, "int"));
$deleterecord = mysql_query($query_deleterecord, $example) or die(mysql_error());
$row_deleterecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($deleteecord);
$totalRows_deleterecord = mysql_num_rows($deleterecord);
```

---

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="Delete Record" id="Delete Record" value="Delete Record" />
    </label>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_deleterecord['id']; ?>" />
  </form>
```

How shall I display a form action status message like ("Record deleted") on the same page with pure php syntax after it is submitted successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it with pure php, u need to do it using ajax....because its about clientside scripting and server-side scripting...once ur form is submitted, it is redirected to the other php script at the server side...in oreder to publish a message in the client-side u just need to use AJAX...thats the only possibilty in my view

Comment: I've already integrated form submission status message into several form related web applications based on pure php syntax but unfortunately I'm missing something in this case and can't get it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

After successful deletion, you create your status message,

```
// After mysql delete command
$msg = urlencode("Record deleted");
```

Edit your `header` command to look like this

```
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo . ?msg={$msg}));
```

Then choose where ever you want to display the message on your page and put the code

```
echo isset($_GET['msg']) ? urldecode($msg) : ''; // This line will display the content of the variable $msg if it is set
```

I can see that you are submitting the form on the same page, you don't need to use the `header` function, in that case, you would change the status message and display message to look like this

```
$msg = "Record deleted";
echo isset($msg) ? $msg : ''; // This line will display the content of the variable $msg if it is set
```

The second method will be faster.

Comment: The first solution gives  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `'.'` in  `header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo . ?msg={$msg}));` when the variable `$msg` is defined after mysql result in the following manner:                               `mysql_select_db($database_example, $example);  
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $example) or die(mysql_error());  
$msg = urlencode("Record deleted");`  On the other hand second solution doesn't print any status message on page after the form is submitted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem finally.

The trick is to assign a query string (key/value pair) to the header location variable or directly replace the header location variable with it's associated value.

Then to switch the query string (key/value pair) in association with function and form variable and wrap a div with it where the form action status message should be displayed on page after successful submission.